# How to clean up windows server 2008 backups

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup

I have a windows 2008 server which is backing up it's primary drive to a local hard disk.

Because this server doesn't change very often, I only execute it manually when worthwhile changes occur.

So far, I've accrued 13 backups that are on disk.  Considering I really only want the last 2; how can I clear those out?

**UPDATE:**
Just to be clear, this question is about the windows server operating system; not SQL server.

Comment: How are you backing up?  Are you using the native tool, a third party, or some kind of copy utility like robocopy?

Comment: I'm using the built in backup utility that ships with Windows Server.

Comment: Oh dear God, I'm ignorant.  I'm deleting my post that showed clearing out _SQL_ 2008 backups.......  Oh please, Friday, get here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm loading up Windows Server Backup on a test server to confirm, but the following post should help:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsbackup/thread/d5302218-91ce-4f02-9fba-9c91e9027f69

> For Volume Shadow copy based backups,
>   there is no direct way to set the
>   maximum size for backup with wbadmin.
>   Since Windows Server Backup relies on
>   shadow copies for versioning, you can
>   use the MAX DIFF AREA Size to control
>   how much space is allocated for
>   storing versions.
>
> Moreover, the old backup version will
>   keep growing until all free space is
>   used up, Windows Server Backup will
>   automatically delete the old version
>   backup to make space for newer ones.

You would adjust this threshold here: Volume ->settings -> use limit -> XXX MB

Or, you may also use "vssadmin resize" command line to increase the amount of storage for shadow copies limit.

```
vssadmin resize shadowstorage /for=<ForVolumeSpec> /on=<OnVolumeSpec> /maxsize=<MaxSizeSpec>
```

ex. Vssadmin resize shadowstorage /for=F: /on=C: /Maxsize=900MB

Answer (score 0):

Doing it by date is easy from a Powershell script e.g.

```
$Days = 30
$TargetFolder = "D:\temp"

$Now = Get-Date
$LastWrite = $Now.AddDays(-$Days)
$Files = get-childitem $TargetFolder -include *.bkf | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -le "$LastWrite"}

foreach ($File in $Files)
{ write-host "Deleting File $File" -foregroundcolor "Red";
  Remove-Item $File
}
```

This deletes all *.bkf files in the folder D:\temp older than 30 days.

With some headscratching you could adapt this to keep only a set number of files. You'd have to sort the output from get-childitem by reverse date and skip the first n files.

JR

Comment: Server 2008 doesn't use bkf files any more...